# knockoutjs - multiple bindings on click event

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

I would like to know if it is possible to create multiple bindings on an event in knockout.js

example:

```
<span data-bind="click: function1 function2, attr: {}"></span>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try to use

```
<span data-bind="click: function() { function1(); function2() }"></span>
```

Comment: yes i already had this version, but i hoped for a more elegant way to do this. but thanks anyway

Comment: I think @v2p solution is very elegant in my opinion. This is what Javascript is all about.

Comment: @Chaitanya I think what he is meaning is that it's inline javascript which -IMO- isn't very elegant.

Comment: @hofnarwillie, Actually, I think that problem "I want to call 2 functions by one click" in general should be solved by moving such logic away from View layer and placing inside "Business logic" layer (in terms of Knockout it should be View Model). So here we have some kind of  "Unclear goal - unclear solution" case.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I accidentally used the MooTools *typeOf()* without thinking. Fixed.

---

Here's what I came up with. I admit it's overkill for most situations but the syntax is a bit cleaner on the template side:

View Model:

```
var ViewModel = new function() {
    this.call = function(functions,args) {
        if (!(functions instanceof Array))
            functions = [functions];
        if (!(args instanceof Array))
            args = [args];

        return function() {
            for (var i = 0, l = functions.length; i < l; i++) {
                functions[i].apply(this,args);
            }
        }
    }

    this.testValue=ko.observable('Click me!');
    this.click1 = function(foo) {
        this.testValue('click1 ' + foo);
        alert(1);
    }
    this.click2 = function(foo) {
        this.testValue('click2 ' + foo);
        alert(2);
    }
}
```

and template

```
<span data-bind="click:call([click1,click2],['Test value'])">Test span</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout custom simple binding `clickArray`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickArray = {

  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var handlers = valueAccessor();

    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
      click: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
          handlers[i].apply(this, arguments);
        }
      }
    });
  }

};
```

Then you wrap some HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
  <a data-bind="clickArray: [bar, baz]">Click</a>
</div>
```

…and make a model:

```
var viewModel = {
    bar: function () {
      alert('Bar!');
    },

    baz: function () {
      alert('Baz.');
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hejdav/qmfem8t3/6/

Answer (score -1):

I tried this in my code and it seems to work:

```
<button data-bind="click: viewMode.bind($data, 'view'), click: itemUpdate">
```

Comment: `<li data-bind="css: { active: navTab.isActive }, click: function(){alert(1)}, click: function(){alert(2)}">` only alerts "2". Yours works because its registering your first `click` and rewriting it with the second one. If you return a `function` from "`viewMode.bind(...)`", you cannot expect it to call it.