# Knockout JS cross-view model referencing

Tags: knockout.js

I have an aggregate view that combines multiple views in knockout (Sort of like a partial view, the master view allows me to access view models regardless of the view page). Is there some way to refer to a property in another view in knockout? I have an input box that I want to fire an ajax request in one VM, but I also need it to fire a request in another vm. I know I could chain them together inside one of the VM's, but I don't want to explicitly reference a separate VM if I don't have to.

the master view has the form of

```
function AggregateViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.vm1= new FirstViewModel();
   self.vm2= new SecondViewModel();
   self.vm3= new ThirdViewModel();
```

}

and I want to bind the input similar to

```
<input data-bind="click: vm1.inputValue, click: vm2.inputValue">
```

so that I can fire both ajax events on the same click event.

Thanks for any help/comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761457/knockoutjs-multiple-bindings-on-click-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not bind two click handlers, second will overwrite first. But you can aggregate them on you view model:

```
function AggregateViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.vm1 = {
        handleClick: function () {
            console.log('vm1');
        }
    };

    self.vm2 = {
        handleClick: function () {
            console.log('vm2');
        }
    };
    self.vm3 = {};

    self.handleClick = function () {
        console.log('Wrapper');
        self.vm1.handleClick();
        self.vm2.handleClick();
    };
}
```

And bind to that single function:

```
<input type="button" value="test" data-bind="click: handleClick" />
```

See [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KVkEs/1/), with console turned on.

Comment: This is the right direction to go, and it starts to get into a bigger question of application architecture, specifically, how to organize the behavior of the application conceptually. If we revisit the concept of a ViewModel, we think of it as agnostic of presentation, but still specific to a particular view. Its area of responsibility can be limited to acting as a gateway to the rest of the logic within the application. I would consider employing a service oriented architecture (or anything else of your choosing) that encapsulates most the actual behavior in the app. VMs just provide access.

Comment: This is good, but how do I add an input that both methods can access? Put an observable in the AggregateViewModel? each handle click function takes a string as a parameter, and this string comes from a single input field.