# Multiple click binding on element only executes one in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a dropdown menu which when clicked, should both open a modal dialog and close the dropdown menu. I have stored this functionality within two separate functions, like so:

```
self.toggleDropdownVisibility = function () {
    self.showDropdown(!self.showDropdown());
};

// and

self.toggleModalVisibility = function () {
    self.showModal(!self.showModal());
};
```

With my HTML being:

```
<li data-value="manage" data-bind="click: toggleModalVisibility, click: toggleDropdownVisibility">
```

The problem is however, when I use this syntax, only the first function is executed (in this case, `toggleModalVisibility`), and if I reverse the order, `toggleDropdownVisibility` is called. How can I bind two click events to a single element and have them both execute?

Comment: See if the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761457/knockoutjs-multiple-bindings-on-click-event) helps you.

Comment: @hunch_hunch already seen it, none of those answers work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an "onClick" function to your model and point your declarative click binding to that, then call the two functions you would like to call from the onClick function.

Javascript:

```
self.toggleDropdownVisibility = function () {
    self.showDropdown(!self.showDropdown());
};

self.toggleModalVisibility = function () {
    self.showModal(!self.showModal());
};

self.onClick = function () {
    self.toggleDropdownVisibility();
    self.toggleModalVisibility();
};
```

Html:

```
<li data-value="manage" data-bind="click: onClick">
```