# Adding multiple knockout click events to a link

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a link that has multiple bindings:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="text:reportOutcomeDesc, attr:{id:reportOutcomeId}, event:{click:$root.editRepOutcome, click:$root.showRepGrid}"></a>
```

When I click the link, the showRepGrid function is called, but the editRepOutcome isn't.  I suspect it's a syntax issue that is the reason why the last function is only called.

What is the correct syntax to have multiple click events raised with one click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knockoutjs - multiple bindings on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761457/knockoutjs-multiple-bindings-on-click-event)

Answer (score 1):

Call one click event, and within that function, call your two child functions `editRepOutcome` and `showRepGrid`.